# Is it possible to create a box with a fixed dimension, regardless of how large its content is?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

Is that possible to create a box (without frame) so that, even though its content is pretty big, it only occupies a small space in the text follow. For example, a tikz picture, however large it is, only takes a size of 1cm x 1cm if you put it into a text flow.

---

**Update:** To clarify the confusions, I meant to draw a box, visually large, but only occupy a small space on the text flow. For example, like the star in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear (based on the confusion in the answers): do you want to shrink a large box into a small one, or do you want to create a "virtual" small box with content of arbitrarily large visual size but only a fixed typographic size on the page?

Comment: Also, with tikz there are better ways to make it not take up space.  See the `overlay` key.

Comment: @RyanReich: The latter one.

Comment: @RyanReich - Could you elaborate on what you mean by "a virtual small box with content of arbitrarily large visual size"?

Comment: @Mico I meant a "virtual bounding box", a container that takes up some made-up amount of physical space but whose "ink" can be anything, even outside the box.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\raisebox` to set the height (and depth) of the box and `minipage` to set its width. For example,

```
\raisebox{0pt}[1cm][0pt]{%
  \begin{minipage}{1cm}%
    % Your content goes here.
  \end{minipage}%
}
```

will make a box that rises 1cm above the baseline and is 1cm wide. For more information, see [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes).

Comment: Did you mean to write about the command `\resizebox`?

Comment: @Mico `\resizebox` stretches its contents to fit the new size; whereas `\raisebox` and `minipage` use their own dimensions without modifying the contents (assuming the contents of the `minipage` is one box), so that the contents are larger than the box reserved for them. Of course, it's not entirely clear whether trVoldemort wants the contents resized or not.

Comment: This seems to be the LaTeX version of the plain TeX solution `\hbox to 1cm{\hss\vbox to 1cm{\vss <content>\vss}\hss}`, with the bonus of likely not having forgotten some technical detail.

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP is asking for. You may want to add a complete MWE with an image showing the result.

Answer (score 3):

As Ryan Reich points out you can use the `overlay` key to make `tikz` ignore the path/picture contents.

From there on you have a number of choices which do not have to involve `tikz`. But here are two 'tikz-based' ideas:

Firstly, you can use the  `trim left` and `trim right` keys to set the width (not sure which version of `PGF` these keys came in) and the `baseline` key to vertically align the picture.

However, much greater control can be obtained using the `\useasboundingbox` command in the `tikzpicture`, which I've tidied up in a `picture corners` key:

```
\documentclass[border=0.25in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{%
    star in text/.style={
        shape=star,
        draw,
        minimum size=1cm,
        star point ratio=2,
    },
    picture width/.style={
        trim left=-#1/2, 
        trim right=#1/2,
    },
    picture corners/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        execute at end picture={
            \useasboundingbox #1 rectangle #2;
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}{0.5in}
\centering

ab\tikz[picture width=1ex, baseline=-0.5ex]\node[overlay, star in text]{};cd

\vskip0.5in

ab\tikz[picture corners={(-0.5ex, -0.5ex) and ++(1ex, 1ex)}]\node[overlay, star in text]{};cd


\vskip0.5in

ab\tikz[picture corners={[draw] (-0.5cm, -0.5cm) and ++(0.5cm, 0.5cm)}]\node[overlay, star in text]{};cd

\vskip0.5in

ab\tikz[picture corners={[draw] (-0.5cm, 0cm) and ++(0.5cm, 0.5cm)}]\node[overlay, star in text]{};cd

\vskip0.5in

ab\tikz[picture corners={[draw] (0cm, 0cm) and ++(0.5cm, 0.5cm)}]\node[overlay, star in text]{};cd

\vskip0.5in

ab\tikz[picture corners={[draw] (0cm, -0.5cm) and ++(0.5cm, 0.5cm)}]\node[overlay, star in text]{};cd

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The command `\resizebox` of the [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package can "resize" existing boxes into new boxes of specified horizontal and vertical lengths. To leave one of the resized lengths unspecified, supply `!` as the parameter.

The following example shows how a "large box" (a black rectangle measuring 4cm wide and 3cm tall) can be "fit" into a new, smaller box of width set at 1cm. Of course, in practice you would replace `\bigbox` with a real diagram, graphic, table, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\bigbox}{\rule{4cm}{3cm}} % just a big black rectangle
\begin{document}
The small box containing the big box: \resizebox{1cm}{!}{\bigbox}

For reference, the big box: \bigbox
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\useanchorwidth` parameter of the `stackengine` package is intended for what you wish, though one has a few complications to overcome.  In the first image, I just set a large star inline.  In the second image, I use the `\stackon` macro of `stackengine` (with a 0pt baseline shift on a long stack) to overlay the star over a space.  By default, the stack width is the total width, in this case the star width.  So in the third attempt, I set `\useanchorwidth` true, and then the star width becomes the width of the space only.  The problem is that since the star is set *after* the "ab", it overwrites it.

In the final result, I reverse the order of the stack, that is, I stack `ab~cd` atop the star, so it does not overwrite the "ab";  however, the overall width is that of the star (the anchor),  so I have to restack that atop a blank rule the width of `ab~cd` in order to achieve the right spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\bigstar{\scalebox{3.5}{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\color{yellow}$\largestar$}}}
\begin{document}
Inline: ab\bigstar cd

Stackon (w/ width): ab\stackon[0pt]{~}{\bigstar}cd

\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
stackon (useanchorwidth): ab\stackon[0pt]{~}{\bigstar}cd

double stackon (useanchorwidth): \stackon[0pt]{\rule{\widthof{ab~cd}}{0ex}}{%
  \stackon[0pt]{\bigstar}{ab~cd}}

\end{document}
```

[image]